# Change Install Directory If Running Catalina But Not on Mojave

Tags: python, macos, if-statement, macos-catalina, readdirectorychangesw

Needing to run the appblocker software in our macs in our corporate environment. Currently, the code / appblocker works on Mojave but not Catalina due to the dual hard drive issue it creates (link below).

Hopefully it's an easy one but I cant get it to work. I need a piece of python code, where if the user is on MacOS Catalina, it changes the directory and runs the appblocker, if it is on Mojave, just run the appblocker normally. I've linked all the resources I've used below in including Catalina's dual hard drive, and where I got the appblocker from (recommendation from our vendor.)

The code I use can be found under the github link below under AppBlocker.py

https://github.com/erikberglund/AppBlocker

https://www.launchd.info/

https://www.macworld.com/article/3451363/why-you-might-see-a-new-data-disk-in-catalina.html

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to run this on your systems to double check the version numbers,  but something like this should work:

```
import platform, os

if int(platform.release()[:2])==19:
    #we are on Catalina
    os.chdir("NEW FOLDER")

#run rest of code....
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply! just to clarify, under #run rest of code... do i paste the entirety of the appblocker in there and then again under #run normally...

Comment: Just edited answer. Realised that either way you are going to run the appblocker code, the only difference is if you change folder for Catalina or not. If my answer helped please feel free to upvote it and mark it as an answer so that anyone with a similar problem can find a solution.

Comment: Will definitely upvote. Spacing is getting all jacked but clarifying only thing I need to put before the appblocker code is: 

import platform, os

if int(platform.release()[:2])==19:
    #we are on Catalina
    os.chdir("/System/Volumes/Data")


#insert rest of appblocker code here

Comment: Yes that should work. If the current working directory, when the script is initially started, is important then you'll need to save it as a variable before the `os.chdir` section, using `old_directory=os.getcwd()` then after you've run the appblocker code return to the original folder using `os.chdir(old_directory)`

Comment: would our post install script need to be changed? It's as follows: #! /bin/bash
/bin/chmod +x /usr/local/bin/AppBlocker.py

Comment: I do super appreciate you taking your time to help me!

Comment: I assume so yes, if the install location has changed then you'd need to update later references to were it is installed